# problem with reinitiate an array in the state

Tags: arrays, react-native, state

I am trying to use the content of an array.
foreach item beeing used i delete it and continu using the array.

The problem is that when i want to reinit the array with the rest of that array, it doesn't work when i use a setState, but when i touch directly the array, it's ok.
Can you tell me what's the problem in my program ?

thanks for help.

this code is OK but i touch directly to the state

```
class test extends PureComponent {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        arrayToUse: listdata
    }
}

UseArray = async () => {

    console.log("initArray", this.state.arrayToUse)
    console.log("arrayLength", this.state.arrayToUse.length)

    while (this.state.arrayToUse.length > 0) {

        console.log("while - step1", this.state.arrayToUse)
        console.log("while - step2", this.state.arrayToUse[0].name)

        this.state.arrayToUse = this.state.arrayToUse.slice(1)

    }
```

This one is KO: why ?

```
class test extends PureComponent {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        arrayToUse: listdata
    }
}

UseArray = async () => {

    console.log("initArray", this.state.arrayToUse)
    console.log("arrayLength", this.state.arrayToUse.length)

    while (this.state.arrayToUse.length > 0) {

        console.log("while - step1", this.state.arrayToUse)
        console.log("while - step2", this.state.arrayToUse[0].name)

        let nextState = this.state.arrayToUse.slice(1)

        this.setState({
            arrayToUse: nextState
        })

    }
```

Comment: You cannot change the state value like this `this.state.arrayToUse = this.state.arrayToUse.slice(1)`, you should use useState function to update state, that's why your 2nd code is working

Comment: @MahdiN It looks he says work in 1st code?

Comment: @高鵬翔 Ah ok I understood the opposite, really strange behaviour!

Comment: Could you `console.log(nextState)` after `let nextState = this.state.arrayToUse.slice(1)`, I doubt you could't get the value like this...?

Comment: @MahdiN : Yes, it's my first code wich is working, and i know that's is forbidden to use this king of method.

Comment: @高鵬翔 : when i console.log nextState, i have the rest of my array (only the second item) correctly. the strange is that it seem to not be set to my arrayToUse by my setState. My while never end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let nextState = this.state.arrayToUse

nextState.slice(1);

this.setState({
     arrayToUse: nextState
})
```

This way you will make sure you are working with a copy of the array and not the actual array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare and setstate out of while loop?

Everytimes you called setstate, it will rerender once, I'm not sure if it will work true?
But you can try something like this below, or just declare and setstate out of while using your code.

```
UseArray = async () => {

    console.log("initArray", this.state.arrayToUse)
    console.log("arrayLength", this.state.arrayToUse.length)
    let nextState = this.state.arrayToUse;
    while (nextState.length > 0) {

        console.log("while - step1", nextState)
        console.log("while - step2", nextState[0].name)

        nextState = nextState.slice(1);
    }
    // out of while
    this.setState({
        arrayToUse: nextState
    })
}
```